# Redirect the user where he last visited - Node, Express, EJS

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, redirect, ejs

I have blog with ten articles. I already have login and registration system in my blog. When the user logged in and read some article left out the website. When he revisited the site I want the user to redirect to where he left. example if the user read 4th article and left, when he revisit I want to redirect the user to that same 4th article. I'm using Node express as backend. EJS as the frond end. I'm looking for a complete explanation of this concept because I'm very new to these type of concepts.

Comment: In that case using cookie solves the problem. Visiting history is not so important to authenticate so saving page order in cookie and loading it on front pages whenever the user redirect the page. Related document [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save that inside cookies if you are familiar with it or you can just define something like "lastVisitedBlog" inside your database to keep this data.

Comment: Any reference code can you please provide me?

Comment: @Change It depends on which strategy you choose. For cookies as **jacobkim** mentioned [mdn docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie) is good enough to handle this. If you prefer database  then what is your database?

Comment: JSON file as database

Comment: @Change Add a property inside your JSON that is null by default. Each time a user viewed a blog, just update that property inside your user's JSON.